# Automatically add EditText below when the previous has been filled

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, layout-inflater

I have a `xml` file: `row.xml` which contains a `EditText` (*et*) and a Spinner.
The activity starts, I "inflate" `row.xml` in a View and I set a listener that - when *et* changes, a `row.xml` is automatically inflated.My code is like below.

```
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="15dp"
    android:paddingRight="15dp"
    android:paddingTop="3dp"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp">
  <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/spinnerDay"
        android:id="@+id/nameUser"
        android:theme="@style/myEditText"
        android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
        />
  <Spinner
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="38dp"
        android:id="@+id/spinnerDay"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:popupBackground="#FFFFFFFF"
        android:background="@drawable/selector_spinner">
  </Spinner>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My problem is to set a listener for the new row in order to repeat the trick.

```
LinearLayout v = new LinearLayout(context);
v.addView(rowView);
View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
((LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.userList)).addView(v);
```

`R.id.userList` is the View where I inflate  `row.xml`

Listener for EditText

```
((EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nameUser)).setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
 @Override
 public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
  LinearLayout v = new LinearLayout(view.getContext());
  v.addView(rowView);
  ((LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.userList)).addView(v);
  return false;
 }
});
```

I am not an expert programmer so I do ask: what is the best way to a product such an effect and retry the data inserted?

Everything is made more tricky because I am working in `Fragments` in a `FragmentActivity` and I am supposed to get the data in the last one, before confirm...how can I save the et's content?

Any help will be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: please post your code to give a better idea

Comment: use tag with your dynamically generated EditText  and set on click listener on it and add them in an edit text array list and use for loop in the end to read text from that field.!